# Suppress Nonadjacent Duplicates in Report

Tags: sql, sorting, crystal-reports

Medical records in my Crystal Report are sorted in this order:

```
...
Group 1: Score [Level of Risk]
  Group 2: Patient Name
...
```

Because patients are sorted by `Score` before `Name`, the report pulls in multiple entries per patient with varying scores - and since duplicate entries are not always adjacent, I can't use `Previous` or `Next` to suppress them. To fix this, I'd like to only display the *latest entry* for each patient based on the `Assessment Date` field - while maintaining the above order.

I'm convinced this behavior can be implemented with a custom SQL command to only pull in the latest entry per patient, but have had no success creating that behavior myself. How can I accomplish this compound sort?

---

Current SQL Statement in use:

```
SELECT "EpisodeSummary"."PatientID",
"EpisodeSummary"."Patient_Name",
"EpisodeSummary"."Program_Value"
"RiskRating"."Rating_Period",
"RiskRating"."Assessment_Date",
"RiskRating"."Episode_Number",
"RiskRating"."PatientID",
"Facility"."Provider_Name",

FROM (
  "SYSTEM"."EpisodeSummary"
  "EpisodeSummary"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "FOOBARSYSTEM"."RiskAssessment" "RiskRating"
  ON (
    ("EpisodeSummary"."Episode_Number"="RiskRating"."Episode_Number")
    AND
    ("EpisodeSummary"."FacilityID"="RiskRating"."FacilityID")
  )
  AND
  ("EpisodeSummary"."PatientID"="RiskRating"."PatientID")
), "SYSTEM"."Facility" "Facility"

WHERE (
  "EpisodeSummary"."FacilityID"="Facility"."FacilityID"
)
AND "RiskRating"."PatientID" IS NOT NULL 

ORDER BY "EpisodeSummary"."Program_Value"
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Most DBMS support windowed functions that you can use to do what you want. Otherwise, you will need to join in a subquery that returns the latest entry grouping by patient.

Comment: can you elaborate...latest entry means? are you trying to limit the group 1 (score) to only one entry or is there any detail after group 2 where you want to limit those records to one entry?

Comment: @Siva "Latest" meaning with the entry with the most recent `Assessment Date` value for that patient. If John Doe has a score of 52 on 12/15 and a score of 12 on 12/13, show only the more recent entry, 52.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL code below may not be exactly correct, depending on the structure of your tables. The code below assumes the 'duplicate risk scores' were coming from the RiskAssessment table. If this is not correct, the code may need to be altered.

Essentially, we create a derived table and create a row_number for each record, based on the patientID and ordered by the assessment date - The most recent date will have the lowest number (1). Then, on the join, we restrict the resultset to only select record #1 (each patient has its own rank #1).

If this doesn't work, let me know and provide some table details -- Should the Facility table be the starting point? are there multiple entries in EpisodeSummary per patient? thanks!

```
SELECT es.PatientID
    ,es.Patient_Name
    ,es.Program_Value
    ,rrd.Rating_Period
    ,rrd.Assessment_Date
    ,rrd.Episode_Number
    ,rrd.PatientID
    ,f.Provider_Name
FROM SYSTEM.EpisodeSummary es
LEFT JOIN (
    --Derived Table retreiving highest risk score for each patient)
    SELECT PatientID
        ,Assessment_Date
        ,Episode_Number
        ,FacilityID
        ,Rating_Period
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY Assessment_Date DESC
            ) AS RN -- This code generates a row number for each record. The count is restarted for every patientID and the count starts at the most recent date.
    FROM RiskAssessment
    ) rrd
    ON es.patientID = rrd.patientid
        AND es.episode_number = rrd.episode_number
        AND es.facilityid = rrd.facilityid
        AND rrd.RN = 1 --This only retrieves one record per patient (the most recent date) from the riskassessment table 
INNER JOIN SYSTEM.Facility f
    ON es.facilityid = f.facilityid
WHERE rrd.PatientID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY es.Program_Value
```

Comment: This might be just what we need! I'll try it out as soon as I can and get back to you with either an Accept or more questions.

Comment: Great! Let me know. Another option is to have Crystal conditionally suppress records - take a look at this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443938/crystal-reports-group-sorting The SQL Command is **MUCH** more efficient because the database server only returns the most recent record, but the Crystal approach has its merit.

Comment: Apparently `User defined SQL Function 'SYSTEM.ROW_NUMBER()' does not exist.` - Am I missing a step?

Comment: What database vendor are you using - mysql, oracle, informix...?

Comment: I'm not sure. We're connecting through an ODBC to tables managed by the client. I'll ask what they used to set it up.

Comment: If you open up the odbc manager (control panel, administrative tools, ofbc) ypu should be able to see the driver that the odbc connection is using. Once we find out, we can find the correct ranking function to use for that vendor. They're may be a generic function, but I'll have to research

Comment: Ok. There's about 20 drivers listed, but Microsoft ODBC for Oracle is among them. Is there a better way to determine the one we're looking for?

Comment: Inside Crystal reports, if you go to Database > Set Datasource Location, you can see all of the data sources the report is using. You should see the name of the connection ,and under "Properties" you can see the type (ODBC) - This should show you which ODBC connection to look at inside the Control Panel. Assuming it is an oracle connection, it looks like you can use the RANK () function instead. RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID 
  ORDER BY Assessment_Date DESC) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm#i1006336

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114784/discussion-between-4444-and-aron).