# Suppress data which appears in different groups, and keep the one with the latest date

Tags: grouping, crystal-reports-2010

My report needs to group and count a set of data, when the data appears in different groups with the same ID and TYPE but different DATE and DECISION, it requires to suppress the data that is not with the latest date and the total count should not include the suppressed data. Can you please help me with this?

**Raw data**

```
   ID              TYPE         DATE               DECISION
  1111              F           12/01/2016         Approved
  1122              E           3/02/2016          Approved
  1111              F           23/01/2016          Refused
  1133              G           3/07/2016           Refused
```

Before grouping, I am able to suppress the first record which is not with the latest date:

```
  ID              TYPE          DATE               DECISION
  1122              E           3/02/2016          Approved
  1111              F           23/01/2016          Refused
  1133              G           3/07/2016           Refused
```

After I group the data by DECISION:

**Group 1 - Approved**

```
   ID              TYPE         DATE               DECISION
  1111              F           12/01/2016         Approved
  1122              E           3/02/2016          Approved
```

**Group 2 - Refused**

```
ID              TYPE            DATE
  1111              F           23/01/2016          Refused
  1133              G           3/07/2016           Refused
```

*Total Count of ID: 4*

**Expected Result:**

**Group 1 - Approved**

```
ID              TYPE            DATE
  1122              E           3/02/2016
```

**Group 2 - Refused**

```
   ID              TYPE         DATE
  1111              F           23/01/2016
  1133              G           3/07/2016
```

*Total Count of ID: 3*

Comment: thanks for fixing my sample data Smita, i had problem upload the screen shot of my table as image :'(

Comment: Can you bring only the latest approved from the database or all calculation needs to be here in Report

Comment: Hi @ItiTyagi sorry I didn't get what you meant?

Comment: Bringing the latest record from the database, by using grouping and max.

Comment: Thanks @ItiTyagi for the reply, I tried it but it did not work as the latest date data need to be selected within different groups, the max only works within one group but not across multiple groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options - If you do not need Crystal to retrieve all of the records, the best option (from a performance standpoint) is to use a custom SQL command.

[Suppress Nonadjacent Duplicates in Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277232/suppress-nonadjacent-duplicates-in-report/37423440#37423440)

If that is not an option, or you need crystal to have all of the records **(For a running total of ALL requests made in the system)**, you can use conditional suppression, but you won't be able to accomplish it by retaining your current grouping.

See this post for configuring a conditional detail suppression. [Crystal Reports group sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443938/crystal-reports-group-sorting/37444511#37444511)

The conditional detail suppression works by adding a number to each record within a group. You can determine which record is number "1" by using Record Sort expert, and then suppressing the details if the record number is greater than 1.

This approach won't work if you have the report grouped by decision first, because the ID is essentially a subset of that decision (thus, 1111 would appear in both decision groups).

If the objective of this report is to get aggregate data, this approach will be fine because you can create running totals which count records when a record is "approved" or refused, even without utilizing any grouping on Decision

[image]

EDIT: This running total will count ALL of the records (ID 1111 would be counted twice). The SQL command is the cleanest way to get you what you need... Another option might be to use a variable. I will research.

Comment: Thanks @Aron for the detailed reply. The user's request was quite complicated and hard to achieve via crystal report but they only need it in the crystal report format. I ended up getting the total count for them using running totals by selecting each decision (the same approach of your last suggestion) and suppressing the data with the same ID and Type but not the latest date (I firstly sorted all the data by ID, Type and Date in descending order). In this case they are not able to view the detailed data in each decision type but they get the total count which is most important to them.

Comment: I was wanting to use variable but I am still new to crystal report and never used variables in any of my past report, even though there are posts on the internet for variables I was not able to relate and create one for this report :( Your answer is quite useful and I am sure I will utilise them in my future reports a lot. Thanks again @Aron.

Comment: That's great - I am glad it helped. I spent some time looking at using variables to achieve this objective, but due to the order of execution that crystal uses (something to research if you use crystal a lot), you cannot use variables inside running total formula. I could not make it work. If you end up needing a variable for anything feel free to post a new question. They a re essential for passing data to and from sub reports, among other things.