# Crystal Reports group sorting

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports, grouping

I have flight data records for each user. The table below shows an example for one user id. I need to group by user_id (show only one row for each user_id) that has the latest flight_date.

When I added grouping by user_id, the result report displays the right flight date, but the rest of the fields come from the last row for each user (highlighted fields).How do I make it show the entire row with the latest date (4th row in my example)? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You don't want to see any of the other rows - just the latest, correct? - edit; is it just a sorting issue?

Comment: Right. Basically, I want to see row 018 - 81 - 03/08/2017 - B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to **see** the most recent record, per userID, based on the flightdate, there are a few options. The most efficient way is to use a custom SQL command, but Crystal can do it by retrieving all of the records, and then suppressing the records you don't want to see.

1.Group the report by USERID (Report > Group Expert > Add the USERID field to the group section)

[image]
2. Sort the records by FlightDate ( Report > Sort Expert > Add FlightDate and select Descending **NOTE: if FlightDate is not a date, we will need to create a formula to convert it into a date first, otherwise Crystal will treat it as a string and 12/2015 will be higher than 1/2016 (for example)**

[image]

3.Create a running total to count the number of records within each group (This is how we will tell Crystal to suppress the records we don't want) 
--Right click "running Total" on the right hand side, select New. Name it whatever you want; under Field To Summarize add FlightDate, change summary to **COUNT**
Leave Evaluate as "For Each Record"
Under Reset, select On Change of Group and select the group for USERID

[image]

The report should look like this
[image]

4. In the Section Expert, select Details and click the formula button next to "Suppress"
   Enter the formula `{#RecountCount} > 1` (Or whatever name your running total has)

Now you should only see one record for each user

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!