# Group by name, then sort by oldest date

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports, grouping

How can I group by names, and then sort by oldest date? Some names have multiple dates so I want to keep the *oldest date* first and suppress any other date associated with that name.

```
A 1/1/2016    
C 8/5/2017    
B 10/2/2017   
C 5/6/2017   
A 10/6/2012   
B 5/15/2013  
A 2/5/2017  
B 4/6/2017
```

I tried creating a group for each name and date, then sorting by ascending order. But when I place Group 2: `Date` above Group 1: `Name`, the names are no longer grouped together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal Reports group sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443938/crystal-reports-group-sorting)

Comment: i was able to find the min date! how do are arrange it oldest to newest now?

Comment: Use "Group sort expert".

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to go about this. Crystal makes use of SQL to get your data in the first place, so you're able to write your own SQL for record selection. And it's rather easy to write a statement that will only return the oldest date per person, then arrange them by date.

If you prefer to do it in Crystal, you can do either of the following:

1. Group by Name, Sort Ascending. Then make a subrgroup by Date, Ascending. Use a running total (suppressed so you don't see it) to count the number of records, but reset this count on change of Group A. Then suppress the Details section every time this running total is greater than 1.
2. Group by Name. Don't add a second group. Use a subreport that takes the current Name in as a parameter, and returns only the oldest date on record for that name. (Hint: Turn off Can Grow and limit the subreport to one row.)